# Session maintainence in iPhone application

Tags: iphone

Can anyone throw some light on how do we maintain a session in a typical client-server application built for iPhone. It will be great if you could give some sample code for understanding.

Comment: Your question lacks detail. What do you mean by "maintain a session"? What kind of protocol are your client and server using?

Comment: Lets say I am sending a HTTP/HTTPS request from my mobile client to my server which in turn is sending me some response. The application is a kind of shopping cart app where server want to maintain the session with a particular client. How do we handle this in case of iPhone apps. Normally, either server send a session ID along with the server with a defined expiration time and client stores it locally and send it with every further request to server or it can be send through cookies as well.
Am i clear or confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look around on the net, a lot of people are struggling with this, and there are no clear answers. The only "publicized" way to do this is to send the login and password every time that a page is requested. This seems ludicrous, but if anyone out there has another method, they are keeping it to themselves.